# Error in accessing repository using SSH on bitbucket

Tags: linux, ssh, bitbucket

I had set up SSH keys on bitbucket account a year ago. But now when I push, I get the following error : "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host fatal: Could not read from remote repository."

It was working at the time of creation. In the middle, I updated my ubunut from 12 to 14.

Comment: If your keys are old, Ubuntu's ssh may not like them.  By 'old', I think I mean 'DSA', which OpenSSH has deprecated and will refuse to use by default.

Comment: The keys are RSA keys.